# $f(z):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{t-z} d\mu(t)$ show $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}iyf(iy)=-\mu(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, measure-theory

I have some trouble with part b)

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure (i.e finite measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$). Define the function
$$f(z):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{t-z} d\mu(t) z\in \frac{\mathbb{C}}{\mathbb{R}}$$
(a) Determine $f(z)$ if $\mu$ is the Dirac measure at the point $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, that is
$\mu(A) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
   1 & \mbox{if } \alpha \in A \\
   0 & \mbox{if } \alpha \not \in A
 \end{array}
\right.
$
(b) Show (for general $\mu$)
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}iyf(iy)=-\mu(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$
\begin{proof}

ad a):
$$f(z):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{t-z} d\mu(t) =\frac{1}{\alpha - z}$$
because $\mu $ is the Dirac point measure.

ad b): I am really stuck here :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(a):** Your calculation is correct.

**(b):**
Note that for $y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$:

$$iy f(iy)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{iy}{t-iy} d\mu(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\frac{t}{iy}-1} d\mu(t)$$

We have $\left|\frac{1}{\frac{t}{iy}-1}\right|\le 1$ and $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Set $g(t)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\frac{t}{iy}-1}$. The limit exists for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. It is zero whenever $t\not=0$ and $-1$ if $t=0$. That is, $g(t)=0$ for $t\not=0$ and $g(0)=-1$.

We conclude by the dominated convergence theorem:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty} iy f(iy) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\frac{t}{iy}-1} d\mu(t)=\int_\mathbb{R} g(t) d\mu(t)=\int_{\{0\}}g(t)d\mu(t)+\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}}g(t)d\mu(t)\\
&= \int_{\{0\}} -1\cdot d\mu(t)+\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}} 0\cdot d\mu(t)=-\int_{\{0\}}d\mu(t)=-\mu(\{0\})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks again, but I have one more question. I don't understand the last equality, it is a bit too fast for me to see this. Could you perhaps explain that last step, please?

Comment: @user41725: Do you understand it now?